Использование своего middleware и multer в одном запросе express
var upload = multer();

const authHandler = async function (request, response, next) {
    let user = null;

    if (request.headers.authorization) {
        user = await authUserInteractor(request.headers.authorization);
    } else {
        response.status(401);
    }

    if (user) {
        next();
    } else {
        response.status(401);
    }
};

app.post("/createProduct", authHandler, upload.array('product_images', 5), async (request, response) => {
    ...
}

Запрос не обрабатывается, то что внутри app.get вообще не вызывается, то что внутри authHandler тоже не вызывается.
компилятор не ругается, в запросах где только authHandler или только upload.array('product_images', 5) все работает. Почему оно не работает с двумя? Может у multer есть какая-то особенность работы middleware?

то что внутри app.get вообще не вызывается так у тебя app.post()... Насколько я читал про middleware, они должны "заканчиваться". А это либо next(), либо next(error), либо нечто аналогичное response.send(). В твоем случае есть варианты с "подвисанием" этого middleware...
